# Where is lighttpd.conf? Mybook world 2 whitelight webserver

Tags: media, mybook, lighttpd, directory-listing

I'm attempting to get my Roku streaming box with a channel called Roksbox to stream content off my MyBook World 2 whitelight. I want a directory listing of a certain folder of a share, Media. It's 2012 and this should be way easier.

I've tried the basic instructions for installing apache here http://roksbox.com/home/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=73&Itemid=73, and seemingly got apache running, but couldn't get past a 403 error. Knowing that the admin app is already running as a webserver I've decided to get away from the apache route.

I've found this article. http://martin.hinner.info/mybook/lighttpd.php The problem is that I don't even see a lighttpd directory in /etc. Is this a hidden directory or file? How can I be sure that lighttpd is what server is actually running?

Any hints are welcome. I can provide more info like firmware and whatnot if necessary.

Comment: Do you have the "locate" command on that pc?
try locate lighttpd.conf

Comment: You should decide if you want to stick to apache and fix its error or move to lighttpd (and remove apache, in that case)

Comment: A question: you want to stream movies from your Mybook (I suppose) then why you need a webserver? Can't you use samba or any kind of file sharing service?

Answer (score 2):

You should use (I think about general *nix):

```
find / -name lighttpd.conf
```

This command will allow you to find the file (if it exists) on your pc

Also to check if the software is running using:

```
ps aux | grep lighttpd
```

Answer (score 1):

The init script probably contains the location and name of the config file. It might not be exactly `lighttpd.conf`, and if not a `find` won't succeed. Look for a file in `/etc/init.d/` that is named something like `lighttpd`. It should contain a statement like `DAEMON_ARGS="-f /etc/lighttpd.conf"` which contains the file you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

From root go to:
`/etc/lighttpd/` use `pico lighttpd.conf` to edit it, if that doesn't work then change `pico` to `vi`

Comment: "The problem is that I don't even see a lighttpd directory in /etc"  ???

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of running processes with `ps ax`, `ps aufx`, or try `netstat -ltnp` and similar. If there is no /etc/lighttpd and no lighttpd process, then lighttpd probably isn't included (anymore).